# gpg: Note: '--passphrase' is not considered an option

Tags: gnupg, gpg4win

I am running on Windows.

```
gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.4
libgcrypt 1.8.2
```

I am trying to decrypt multiple files, as follows:

```
gpg --batch --decrypt-files *.gpg  --passphrase secretPassword
```

I get the error:

> Note: '--passphrase' is not considered an option

I am trying to put this in a batch file.

Comment: Have you solved it?

Answer (score 4):

From `gpg --help`

> ...
>
> Syntax: gpg [options] [files]
>
> ...

You should put the options before the files you're working on, so prepend `--passphrase secretPassword` before the `files` part, and not after as you did.